# What is the monitor-like icon on Remote App screen?

Tags: ipad, remote-control

There is a monitor/display like icon at the bottom of the Now Playing screen of the Remote app on iPad. It's just to the right of the genius icon. What is it?

Comment: Just curious, but why didn't you click on it?

Comment: Clicking the icon has no visible effect on the iPad other than highlighting the icon. I was wondering about this too. I wasn't looking at the Mac's screen.

Answer (score 3):

That icon activates the visualiser in iTunes